# Redis error "ReplyError: ERR value is not an integer or out of range"

Tags: node.js, express, redis, express-session

i am trying to store sessions in Redis but giving me an error.
i am using nodejs and express.

`ReplyError: ERR value is not an integer or out of range`

```
import express from 'express';
import redis from 'redis';
import redisConnect from 'connect-redis';
import session from 'express-session';

const app = express();
const redisStore = redisConnect(session);
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

app.use(
    session({
        store: new redisStore({
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 6379,
            client: redisClient,
            ttl: 36000,
        }),
        secret: "ljsaflasjdsffafa",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        name: 'user',
        cookie: {
            path: '/',
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 36000,
            secure: false,
        },
    }),
);

app.listen(3000)
```

it's happening when I try to save session

Answer (score -1):

The `ReplyError` is an indicator that your input is not always correct. You could activate the debug mode to see what is actually passed through. There should also be a bit more information on the error about the data passed through.

Comment: i am new to Redis. how to activate debug mode